# How to parse THIS json reply in react native

Tags: json, react-native, cross-platform, react-native-cli

I'am a noob in react native and i'am writing my first app to read a response from an API. Till now i know how to make the call and get the response and parse the regular replies in an array in the state, but i'am not finding the right way to parse the json reply of this specific form. I tried saving it in an array but its not working.

```
{
"activities": [
    {
        "id": 19,
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 63,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:09:34",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:09:34",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile133.11531268506258.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 19
            },
            {
                "id": 65,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:10:15",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:10:15",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile203.0997630588359.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 19
            },
            {
                "id": 64,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:09:53",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:10:27",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile193.8056151444231.jpg",
                "is_default": true,
                "activity": 19
            },
            {
                "id": 62,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:08:56",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:10:27",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile39.839136995440484.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 19
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "15/05/2020 14:52:54",
        "updated_at": "15/05/2020 14:58:01",
        "title": "Camping",
        "description": "Camp Al Wilayah",
        "category": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 66,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:16:02",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:16:02",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile46.35084778104737.jpg",
                "is_default": true,
                "activity": 21
            },
            {
                "id": 67,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:16:33",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:16:33",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile49.28140513312763.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 21
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:11:22",
        "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:11:22",
        "title": "Aashoura",
        "description": "Majlis Aazaa",
        "category": 12
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 68,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:21:18",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:21:18",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile71.35101359514769.jpg",
                "is_default": true,
                "activity": 18
            },
            {
                "id": 69,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:22:42",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:22:42",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile107.17719628795922.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 18
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "15/05/2020 14:52:11",
        "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:17:34",
        "title": "Takliff",
        "description": "Taklif ceremony",
        "category": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 70,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:42:18",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:43:03",
                "file": "/media/activities/97026390_682458148963323_2038839267676913664_n.mp4",
                "is_default": true,
                "activity": 22
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:24:46",
        "updated_at": "15/05/2020 15:24:46",
        "title": "Laylat Qader",
        "description": "Event of Laylat al Qader",
        "category": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "files": [
            {
                "id": 73,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 17:42:43",
                "updated_at": "15/05/2020 17:42:43",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile47.470692661344614.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 23
            },
            {
                "id": 74,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 18:30:05",
                "updated_at": "26/05/2020 21:34:09",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile28.504968134645907.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 23
            },
            {
                "id": 72,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:51:29",
                "updated_at": "15/07/2020 07:49:27",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile82.57124842095388.jpg",
                "is_default": false,
                "activity": 23
            },
            {
                "id": 71,
                "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:50:59",
                "updated_at": "15/07/2020 07:50:09",
                "file": "/media/activities/newFile3.0461490605067763.jpg",
                "is_default": true,
                "activity": 23
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "15/05/2020 15:50:36",
        "updated_at": "15/07/2020 07:46:38",
        "title": "Zayyana Al Dar",
        "description": "Young generation posts",
        "category": 11
    }
],
"total": 5
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, entire response is inside object bracket `{}`.

So, `response.activities` will give array of a activities.

Then use it like `var x = response.activities`

`var first = x[0]`

`var second = x[1]`

and so on .

Comment: this is my  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(
      "https://dev.libanroot.com:83/islamicapp/api/visitor/activities"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          activities: responseJson.activities,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, i think it is as you told me to do, but still its not filling the activities array.

Comment: Then you missed a point on javascript promises. Go through Promises for better coding

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad for checking the "activities" array in the state by "console.log(this.state.activities)" in the ".then" that is right after the setState function. i thought the code won't move to the second ".then" unless done with the first, so it was getting parsed in the way rock stated but printed in the console before that.